# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

When I run php file,browser shows blank and the error.log file shows following error

> [Tue Mar 11 18:51:37 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:
>   Uncaught  --> Smarty: unable to write file
>   templates_c/wrt531f0de1310f36.31049288 <-- \n  thrown in
>   /var/www/forum/modules/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php
>   on line 44

Comment: That looks like Smarty's `templates_c/` directory (where it stores compiled templates) is not writable by the web server. You need to make it writable by the user your web server runs as.

Comment: is that file/directory writeable by your scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That probably means that either the templates_c directory doesn't exist, or the script has unsufficient rights to store files in that folder.

You can make that folder writeable by making adjustments to the permissions using [`chmod`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod). You can do this in most of today's FTP clients. The directory needs to be writable by the user that runs the PHP code (usually www, apache, nobody).

If unsure, set the directory's permissions to `0777` and that should do the trick. But keep in mind that when you set it to `0777`, it is world-writeable, so depending on your setup, you might want to check for the right value.

Comment: This is bad advice.

Answer (score 1):

From the Smarty documentation, they recommend using 770 for the templates_c and cache directories. They go on to say that if you have issues, trying 775 may work still.

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/installing.smarty.basic

```
chown nobody:nobody /path/to/templates_c/
chmod 770 /path/to/templates_c/

chown nobody:nobody /path/to/cache/
chmod 770 /path/to/cache/
```

When I got this running I assigned the directories go my user and the group www-data.

```
chown darren:www-data /path/to/templates_c/
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. First check SElinux status by command `getenforce`. If Enforcing you need to disable it. It should be Disabled and reboot and check once is it disabled.
2. Then if there is no folder create it `mkdir /path/to/templates_c`
3. and then give write access `chown -R apache:apache /path/to/templates_c`

Answer (score -1):

chown www-data:www-data -R (FOLDER-ARCHIVE)

Answer (score -3):

give `777` permission to  `templates_c` folder

Comment: see vdwijngaert's answer, this is the most open setting, so not really recommended for a production server